# Conditional Tooltip Based On Checkbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I've got a checkbox and a button in my WPF MVVM app. If the checkbox is checked I want a tooltip on the button that says "x" and if it's unchecked the tooltip should say "y".

Anyone know the best way to do this? I think it could be done with a separate property in my view model, but maybe there's an easier way to do this in just the xaml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just add/remove, or change visibility programmatically in a checkbox changed event?

Comment: @dbrad that isn't the idea of MVVM / WPF

Comment: @dbrad besides, mm8's answer shows how to make this construction reusable, and declared completely in xaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chk" Content="CheckBox" />
<Button Content="Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="y" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="x" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry just getting back to this now. I wasn't clear in my question that I want the tooltip on the button to change not the tooltip on the checkbox based on the checkbox's state. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: You should ask a new question if you have another issue, not change your original question into a completely different one. Anyway, I edited my answer according to your latest question.

Comment: It's not a completely different question. I edited the question to be more clear about what I was originally asking therefore I will not be asking a new second question. Why would I have even included the button in the first place if that was not the intended question?